# google-chrome can't click on dropdown menus

Tags: google-chrome, menu

I'm running ubuntu 20.04, and am finding that on many but not all occasions, I cannot click on drop-down menus when I use `google-chrome`.      This problem arises on all of my laptops, which are set up identically.     A recent example of my problem is illustrated with the following website.

https://www1.onlinebanking.suntrust.com/UI/login#/enrollment

It prompts for Account type.    The dropdown offers 5 options, including Mortgage.
When I click on Mortgage nothing happens.      I have to type the word in manually.    I've tried the same URL using `firefox` and `chromium-browser`, and both work as expected, i.e., I click on Mortgage and the click triggers the word appearing in the dialog box.
I've read of other people having problems of a similar nature, but the sites that I've seen all have special circumstances, and don't apply to me.      Could anybody advise how to fix this please?

Comment: Same issue here, did you find a solution?